# How to add hashes to an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a business with 2 employees. Each employee has many messages.

When I run the command:

```
business.employees.each do |employee|
 puts employee.messages.group_by &:from
end
```

I get the correct output:

```
{100=>[#<Message id: 3, content: "Needs more training", from: 100, employee_id: 1>]}

{101=>[#<Message id: 2, content: "Very lazy.", from: 101, employee_id: 2>], 102=>[#<Message id: 1, content: "Fantastic.", created_at: "2014-03-03 12:01:28", updated_at: "2014-03-03 12:01:28", from: 102, employee_id: 2>]}
```

But I don't want to puts the output I want to add each hash to an array so that I can display them.

So when I run the command

```
grouped_messages = []
business.employees.each do |employee|
 grouped_messages << employee.short_messages.group_by &:from
end
```

I get the error: `expecting keyword_end`

Comment: Try it without omitting the parentheses.

Comment: My first thought as well @sawa

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing parentheses, this should work:

```
grouped_messages = []
business.employees.each do |employee|
 grouped_messages << employee.short_messages.group_by(&:from)
end
```

A better alternative should be to use `map`:

```
grouped_messages = business.employees.map do |employee| 
  employee.short_messages.group_by &:from
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't omit the parentheses:

```
grouped_messages << employee.short_messages.group_by(&:from)
```

Answer (score -1):

Parenthesis is missing around `&:from` which is causing error. Change it it to `(&:from)`